# How to pass a specific implementation of a class to a generic in Autofac

Tags: c#, autofac

I have a generic class `EfRepository<>` which is the implementation of the interface `IRepository<>`. This class takes `DbContext` as a parameter of its constructor. I need to inject exactly a specific subclass of `DbContext`, i.e. `ApplicationDbContext`. How to do this in Autofac?

This is what I have, and what I want:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfRepository<>))
       .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
       .InstancePerDependency();

//The following line doesn't even compile but perhaps it can make my question clearer
builder.Register(c => new EfRepository<>(new ApplicationDbContext()))
       .As(typeof(EfRepository<>))
       .InstancePerDependency();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything special, just to register `ApplicationDbContext` as `DbContext`

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfRepository<>))
       .As(typeof(IRepository<>));
builder.Register<ApplicationDbContext>()
       .As<DbContext>();
```

If you want to register a specific `DbContext` for `EfRepository<>` you could use the `WithParameter` method

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfRepository<>))
       .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
       .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(DbContext), 
                      (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<DbContext>("application")); 

builder.Register<ApplicationDbContext>()
       .Named<DbContext>("application");
```

I use a named registration to benefit the `Autofac` instanciation instead of direct isntanciation.

You can find more information here : [Passing parameters to register](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/register/parameters.html)